# Is there a better way to send variables to blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm still learning Laravel and how the blade system all works..

I'm wondering what the better way of doing something is and that something is; I've done a query to pull a row from the database and then I want to put that query into an array so I can pick out whatever column I want.

Then I want to pass that to my `home.blade.php` and be able to use `{{ $name }}` for example. T

This is what I've got:

*TO NOTE: THIS WORKS THE WAY I WANT IT TO BUT IM SURE IM DOING IT THE LONG WAY (WRONG) ROUND.*

HomeController.php

```
<?php
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function home() {

        $hero_query = DB::table('heros')->where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('hero');

        if($hero_query) {
            $owner_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $user = DB::table('heros')->where('owner_id', $owner_id)->first();

            $name = $user->hero;
            $level = $user->level;
            $exp = $user->exp;
            $str = $user->str;
            $atk = $user->atk;
            $def = $user->def;
            $int = $user->int;
            $blk = $user->blk;


            return View::make('home', array(
                'name'  => $name,
                'level' => $level,
                'exp'   => $exp,
                'str'   => $str,
                'atk'   => $atk,
                'def'   => $def,
                'int'   => $int,
                'blk'   => $blk
            ));
        } else {
            return View::make('home');
        }
    }
}
```

home.blade.php

```
@if($hero = DB::table('heros')->where('owner_id', Auth::user()->id)->pluck('hero'))  
                <form action="{{ URL::route('hero-delete') }}" method="POST">
                    Your hero:<br> 
                    <b>{{ $hero; }}</b> | <input type="submit" value="Delete"><br>
                    <b>Stats:</b> 
                        LvL: {{ $level }}
                        Exp: {{ $exp }}
                        Str: {{ $str }}
                        Atk: {{ $atk }}
                        Def: {{ $def }}
                        Int: {{ $int }}
                        Blk: {{ $blk }}
                </form>
            @else
                <form action="{{ URL::route('hero-create') }}" method="POST">
                    Hero:<br>
                    You do not have a hero, create one!
                    <input type="text" name="hero">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create hero">

                    @if($errors->has('hero'))
                        {{ $errors->first('hero')}}
                    @endif

                    {{ Form::token()}}
                </form>
            @endif
```

Now I'm sure I'm doing it in some stupid moronic way as I'm just starting out.. but could someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the entire `$user` to the view

```
$user = DB::table('heros')->where('owner_id', $owner_id)->first();
return View::make('home', array('user' => $user));
```

Then in your view

```
Str: {{ $user->str }}
Int: {{ $user->int }}
```

and so on.

Comment: Aaaaah, I'm so stupid; I see. So I dont actually have to declare the results of the array for my home.blade to see it? Rather It pushes the entire array and I can then select from it from inside home.blade?

Thanks! Sorry it was such a dumbass question!

Comment: @user3245541 - Except that it isn't an array, it's an object

Comment: what @Mark Baker just said - you pass the $user "object" to the view and keep working with it there, rather than the array of the $user. Gives you the ability to continue using the Eloquent object functions in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing lots of things wrong :(

I fix a little bit the code, but I didn't test it, so use this as a guide to implement what you want.

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function home() {

        $hero = Hero::where('owner_id', '=', $owner_id)->first();

        if($hero)
        {   
            return Response::make('home', array('hero' => $hero->toArray()));
        }
        else
        {
            return Response::make('home');
        }
    }
}
```

The blade template

```
@if(isset($hero))
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'hero-delete', 'method' => 'DELETE')) }} 
        Your hero:<br> 
        <b>{{ $hero->hero }}</b> | <input type="submit" value="Delete"><br>
        <b>Stats:</b> 
        <!-- Here you can implement a foreach for performance -->
            LvL: {{ $hero->level }}
            Exp: {{ $hero->exp }}
            Str: {{ $hero->str }}
            Atk: {{ $hero->atk }}
            Def: {{ $hero->def }}
            Int: {{ $hero->int }}
            Blk: {{ $hero->blk }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@else
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'hero-create')) }}
        Hero:<br>
        You do not have a hero, create one!
        <input type="text" name="hero">
        <input type="submit" value="Create hero">

        @if($errors->has('hero'))
            {{ $errors->first('hero')}}
        @endif
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endif
```